# What is the basis for the claim that the Prophets, Psalms, Torah and Gospel have been corrupted?

Tags: quran, hadith, christianity, judaism, revelation

I'm wondering what is the basis for the claim that the Prophets, Psalms, Torah and Gospel have been corrupted? This is something that I hear a lot from Muslims and I'm just curious what is the foundation for their claim.

Is there a verse in the Qur'an which says this? Or a hadith? What does it say?

Comment: A chunk of this question is answered here: [Which part of the Christian Bible is corrupted?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12884/17163).

Answer (score 1):

Allah tells that in Qur'an in  [2:75](https://legacy.quran.com/2/75) , [2:79](https://legacy.quran.com/2/79) , [3:78](https://legacy.quran.com/3/78) ,
[4:46](https://legacy.quran.com/4/46) , [5:13](https://legacy.quran.com/5/13) , [5:14](https://legacy.quran.com/5/14) , [5:41](https://legacy.quran.com/5/41)

Answer (score -4):

These books are called Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John because they were traditionally thought to have been written by Matthew, a disciple who was a tax collector; John, the "Beloved Disciple" mentioned in the Fourth Gospel; Mark, the secretary of the disciple Peter-----------------the point is......how other books are corrupted...............
the holy quran was written in arabic and acording to history there is no change in quran from the holy prophet's age...............but the gospel was changed  and made it new......only for the requirement of society.......on start of my conversation i have told you ..........plz read on the start

Comment: This doesn't seem much more than a long comment. Please consider taking your time to elaborate a good answer (see [answer]).