# Does the Quran endorse the Bible?

Tags: quran, bible

I am a bit puzzled. I read in this site that the Bible is corrupted, and should not be accepted by Muslims (e.g. [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37874/to-what-extent-have-the-psalms-torah-prophets-and-gospel-been-corrupted?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37875/what-is-the-basis-for-the-claim-that-the-prophets-psalms-torah-and-gospel-have?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12884/which-part-of-the-christian-bible-is-corrupted?noredirect=1&lq=1)). However, whilst reading [this website](http://www.debate.org.uk/debate-topics/apologetic/contrads/), I came across [this text](http://www.debate.org.uk/debate-topics/apologetic/contrads/), which states that "the Qur’an emphatically endorses the Torah and the Gospel as authentic and authoritative revelations from God". Some (long, sorry) quotes:

> The Qur’an, itself, the highest authority for all Muslims, gives authority to the Bible, assuming its authenticity at least up to the seventh-ninth Centuries. Consider the following Suras:
>
> Sura Baqara 2:136 points out that there is no difference between the scriptures which preceded and those of the Qur’an, saying, “…the revelation given to us…and Jesus…we make no difference between one and another of them.” Sura Al-I-Imran 3:2-3 continues, “Allah…He sent down the Law (of Moses) and the Gospel (of Jesus)…as a guide to mankind.” Sura Nisaa 4:136 carries this farther by admonishing the Muslims to, “…Believe…and the scripture which He sent before him.” In Sura Ma-ida 5:47,49,50,52 we find a direct call to Christians to believe in their scriptures: “…We sent Jesus, the son of Mary, confirming the Law that had come before him. We sent him the Gospel… Let the people of the Gospel judge by what Allah hath revealed therein, if any do fail to judge by the light of what Allah hath revealed, they are (no better than) those who rebel…” Again, in Sura Ma-ida 5:68 we find a similar call: “People of the Book!…Stand fast by the law, the Gospel, and all revelation that hath come to you from YOUR LORD. It is the revelation that has come to thee from THY LORD.”
>
> To embolden this idea of the New and Old Testament’s authority we find in Sura 10:94 that Muslims are advised to confer with these scriptures if in doubt about their own, saying: “If thou wert in doubt as to what We have revealed unto thee, then ask those who have been reading the Book from before thee. The truth had indeed come to thee from thy Lord.” And as if to emphasize this point the advice is repeated in Sura 21:7, stating, “…the apostles We sent were but men, to whom We granted inspiration. If ye realize this not, Ask of those who possess the message.”
>
> Finally, in Sura Ankabut 29:46 Muslims are asked not to question the authority of the scriptures of the Christians, saying, “And dispute ye not with the people of the book but say: We believe in the revelation which has come down to us and that which came down to you.”
>
> In fact, **nowhere is there any warning in the Qur’an that the former scriptures had been corrupted, nor that they were contradictory.** If the Qur’an was indeed the final and complete revelation, if it was the seal of all former revelations the Muslims claim, than certainly the author of the Qur’an would have included a warning against that which had been corrupted in the earlier scriptures. But nowhere do we find even a hint that the Bible was contradictory, or indeed that it was corrupted.
>
> There are some Muslims, however, who contend that according to sura 2:140 the Jews and Christians had corrupted their scriptures. This aya says (referring to the Jews), “…who is more unjust than those who conceal the testimony they have from Allah…?” Yet, nowhere does this aya state that the Jews and Christians corrupted their scriptures. It merely mentions that certain Jews have concealed “the testimony they have from Allah.” In other words the testimony is still there (thus the reason the aforementioned suras admonish Muslims to respect the former scriptures), though the adherents of that testimony have chosen to conceal it. If anything this aya is a ringing endorsement to the credibility of those former scriptures, as it assumes a testimony from Allah does exist amongst the Jewish community.

I highlighted the sentence which I found more interesting. Maybe you have some counterexamples.

Comment: What do you mean endorse? Also there are many different Bibles so your question is problematic.

Comment: You can parse what is authentic and what is not in the old and new testaments by using the Quran as a Furkhan (criterion between right and wrong).  When you do this, some of the scripture is authentic and some is not according to how well it concurs with what is in the Quran.

Answer (score 3):

The Qur'an only endorses the Torah and the Gospel that have been **revealed by Allah**, not the versions that are among us now, which we believe contain both a version of the truth as well as corruption.

The quote you posted is a very long quote in specific, and the topic is a wide topic in general, to address in one post. So, I will answer you with titles. Any particular verse or topic that you want to discuss further or in more details, please post a separate question for each verse.

To summarize, in Islam, we have six articles of faith that we have to believe in, and one of them is **the Scripture revealed by Allah** to previous messengers:

> آمَنَ الرَّسُولُ بِمَا أُنزِلَ إِلَيْهِ مِن رَّبِّهِ وَالْمُؤْمِنُونَ كُلٌّ آمَنَ بِاللَّهِ وَمَلَائِكَتِهِ وَكُتُبِهِ وَرُسُلِهِ لَا نُفَرِّقُ بَيْنَ أَحَدٍ مِّن رُّسُلِهِ وَقَالُوا سَمِعْنَا وَأَطَعْنَا ۖ غُفْرَانَكَ رَبَّنَا وَإِلَيْكَ الْمَصِيرُ
>
> The Messenger has believed in what was revealed to him from his Lord, and [so have] the believers. All of them have believed in Allah and His angels and His books and His messengers, [saying], "We make no distinction between any of His messengers." And they say, "We hear and we obey. [We seek] Your forgiveness, our Lord, and to You is the [final] destination."
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-Baqarah 2:285](https://quran.com/2/285)</sub>

I have highlighted the phrase "the Scripture revealed by Allah" as this answers almost all the questions about the verses you mentioned. We believe that Allah revealed Scripture to previous people and that they were entrusted to preserve as revealed (see [Qur'an 5:44](https://quran.com/5/44)), but they corrupted their Scripture.

The article you quoted said that there are some Muslims who contend that [Surat Al-Baqarat 2:140](https://quran.com/2/140/) is the only reference to previous Scripture being corrupted. Actually the phrase about "concealing a testimony" is about knowing that a prophet would come from that area, and the Jewish tribes mentioning that over and over to the Arabs, but when the Prophet ﷺ came to them, they rejected him for not being from the tribe of Levi (or any of the 12 tribes for that matter). Having said that, the verses in the Qur'an and the hadiths that talk about the corruption of previous Scripture are numerous. Such corruption took different forms, and I am going to use verses from the Qur'an alone (no reference to hadiths at this stage) to address your part of the question about the assumption that nowhere in the Qur'an is a mention of former Scriptures having been corrupted:

- Deletions through concealing parts of the revelation:

  > وَمَا قَدَرُوا اللَّهَ حَقَّ قَدْرِهِ إِذْ قَالُوا مَا أَنزَلَ اللَّهُ عَلَىٰ بَشَرٍ مِّن شَيْءٍ ۗ قُلْ مَنْ أَنزَلَ الْكِتَابَ الَّذِي جَاءَ بِهِ مُوسَىٰ نُورًا وَهُدًى لِّلنَّاسِ ۖ تَجْعَلُونَهُ قَرَاطِيسَ تُبْدُونَهَا وَتُخْفُونَ كَثِيرًا ۖ وَعُلِّمْتُم مَّا لَمْ تَعْلَمُوا أَنتُمْ وَلَا آبَاؤُكُمْ ۖ قُلِ اللَّهُ ۖ ثُمَّ ذَرْهُمْ فِي خَوْضِهِمْ يَلْعَبُونَ
  >
  > And they did not appraise Allah with true appraisal when they said, " Allah did not reveal to a human being anything." Say, "Who revealed the Scripture that Moses brought as light and guidance to the people? You [Jews] make it into pages, **disclosing [some of] it and concealing much**. And you were taught that which you knew not — neither you nor your fathers." Say, " Allah [revealed it]." Then leave them in their [empty] discourse, amusing themselves.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al-An'am 6:91](https://quran.com/6/91/)</sub>

  > الَّذِينَ آتَيْنَاهُمُ الْكِتَابَ يَعْرِفُونَهُ كَمَا يَعْرِفُونَ أَبْنَاءَهُمْ ۖ وَإِنَّ فَرِيقًا مِّنْهُمْ لَيَكْتُمُونَ الْحَقَّ وَهُمْ يَعْلَمُونَ
  >
  > Those to whom We gave the Scripture know him as they know their own sons. But indeed, a party of them conceal the truth while they know [it].
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al-Baqarah 2:146](https://quran.com/2/146/)</sub>
- Additions through claiming that some scripture written by people who are neither prophets nor messengers was a revelation from God (in reference to the canonized Gospels we have today as none of them are Jesus's Gospel, and in reference to the epistles of Paul, Peter, and John, and the Revelation):

  > وَإِنَّ مِنْهُمْ لَفَرِيقًا يَلْوُونَ أَلْسِنَتَهُم بِالْكِتَابِ لِتَحْسَبُوهُ مِنَ الْكِتَابِ وَمَا هُوَ مِنَ الْكِتَابِ وَيَقُولُونَ هُوَ مِنْ عِندِ اللَّهِ وَمَا هُوَ مِنْ عِندِ اللَّهِ وَيَقُولُونَ عَلَى اللَّهِ الْكَذِبَ وَهُمْ يَعْلَمُونَ
  >
  > And indeed, there is among them a party who alter the Scripture with their tongues **so you may think it is from the Scripture, but it is not from the Scripture. And they say, "This is from Allah," but it is not from Allah**. And they speak untruth about Allah while they know.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al 'Imran 3:78](https://quran.com/3/78/)</sub>
- Changing the content of what has been revealed by Allah:

  > مِّنَ الَّذِينَ هَادُوا يُحَرِّفُونَ الْكَلِمَ عَن مَّوَاضِعِهِ وَيَقُولُونَ سَمِعْنَا وَعَصَيْنَا وَاسْمَعْ غَيْرَ مُسْمَعٍ وَرَاعِنَا لَيًّا بِأَلْسِنَتِهِمْ وَطَعْنًا فِي الدِّينِ وَلَوْ أَنَّهُمْ قَالُوا سَمِعْنَا وَأَطَعْنَا وَاسْمَعْ وَانظُرْنَا لَكَانَ خَيْرًا لَّهُمْ وَأَقْوَمَ وَلَٰكِن لَّعَنَهُمُ اللَّهُ بِكُفْرِهِمْ فَلَا يُؤْمِنُونَ إِلَّا قَلِيلًا
  >
  > Among the Jews are those who **distort words from their [proper] usages** and say, "We hear and disobey" and "Hear but be not heard" and "Ra'ina," twisting their tongues and defaming the religion. And if they had said [instead], "We hear and obey" and "Wait for us [to understand]," it would have been better for them and more suitable. But Allah has cursed them for their disbelief, so they believe not, except for a few.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat An-Nisa' 4:46](https://quran.com/4/46/)</sub>
- Changing the concept (implied change of Scripture) of what has been revealed to them, e.g., by claiming that Jesus is God:

  > لَقَدْ كَفَرَ الَّذِينَ قَالُوا إِنَّ اللَّهَ هُوَ الْمَسِيحُ ابْنُ مَرْيَمَ ۖ وَقَالَ الْمَسِيحُ يَا بَنِي إِسْرَائِيلَ اعْبُدُوا اللَّهَ رَبِّي وَرَبَّكُمْ ۖ إِنَّهُ مَن يُشْرِكْ بِاللَّهِ فَقَدْ حَرَّمَ اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ الْجَنَّةَ وَمَأْوَاهُ النَّارُ ۖ وَمَا لِلظَّالِمِينَ مِنْ أَنصَارٍ
  >
  > They have certainly disbelieved who say, " Allah is the Messiah, the son of Mary" while the Messiah has said, "O Children of Israel, worship Allah, my Lord and your Lord." Indeed, he who associates others with Allah - Allah has forbidden him Paradise, and his refuge is the Fire. And there are not for the wrongdoers any helpers.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al-Ma'idah 5:72](https://quran.com/5/72/)</sub>

If this is indeed the case, the question arises as to why then in multiple verses there is what appears to some as a form of endorsement. In addressing the verses you mentioned, I will refer to [*Taysīr Al-Karīm Ar-Rahmān*](https://al-maktaba.org/book/42), the *tafsīr* (exegesis) of the Qur'an by Abdur-Rahman ibn Nasir As-Sa'di. If you want to discuss any specific verse in more details and refer to multiple exegeses for comparison and study, then please post a separate question for each verse:

- [Surat Al-Baqarah 2:136](https://quran.com/2/136/) explicitly restricts our belief to **what has been revealed**, not what the people of the Scripture now have in their hands, and indeed we are commanded to make no distinction between any of Allah's revelations:

  > قُولُوا آمَنَّا بِاللَّهِ وَمَا أُنزِلَ إِلَيْنَا وَمَا أُنزِلَ إِلَىٰ إِبْرَاهِيمَ وَإِسْمَاعِيلَ وَإِسْحَاقَ وَيَعْقُوبَ وَالْأَسْبَاطِ وَمَا أُوتِيَ مُوسَىٰ وَعِيسَىٰ وَمَا أُوتِيَ النَّبِيُّونَ مِن رَّبِّهِمْ لَا نُفَرِّقُ بَيْنَ أَحَدٍ مِّنْهُمْ وَنَحْنُ لَهُ مُسْلِمُونَ
  >
  > Say, [O believers], "We have believed in Allah and **what has been revealed** to us and **what has been revealed** to Abraham and Ishmael and Isaac and Jacob and the Descendants and **what was given** to Moses and Jesus and what was given to the prophets from their Lord. We make no distinction between any of them, and we are Muslims [in submission] to Him."
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al-Baqarah 2:136](https://quran.com/2/136/)</sub>
- [Surat Ali 'Imran 3:2-3](https://quran.com/3/2-3/) uses the phrases *nazzala* (Arabic: نزل) to mean His revelation and *ma bayn yadayh* (Arabic: لما بين يديه) which means what he had with him, which the verse clarifies right after that the Scripture being referred to is the Torah and the Gospel that Allah had revealed:

  > اللَّهُ لَا إِلَٰهَ إِلَّا هُوَ الْحَيُّ الْقَيُّومُ نَزَّلَ عَلَيْكَ الْكِتَابَ بِالْحَقِّ مُصَدِّقًا لِّمَا بَيْنَ يَدَيْهِ وَأَنزَلَ التَّوْرَاةَ وَالْإِنجِيلَ
  >
  > Allah — there is no deity except Him, the Ever-Living, the Sustainer of existence. **He has sent down** upon you, [O Muhammad], the Book in truth, confirming what was before it. And **He revealed the Torat and the Gospel**.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al 'Imran 3:2-3](https://quran.com/3/2-3/)</sub>
- [Surat An-Nisa 4:136](https://quran.com/4/136/) again talks about the Scripture that Allah had sent, not what the people of the Scripture have in their hands right now or then:

  > يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا آمِنُوا بِاللَّهِ وَرَسُولِهِ وَالْكِتَابِ الَّذِي نَزَّلَ عَلَىٰ رَسُولِهِ وَالْكِتَابِ الَّذِي أَنزَلَ مِن قَبْلُ وَمَن يَكْفُرْ بِاللَّهِ وَمَلَائِكَتِهِ وَكُتُبِهِ وَرُسُلِهِ وَالْيَوْمِ الْآخِرِ فَقَدْ ضَلَّ ضَلَالًا بَعِيدًا
  >
  > O you who have believed, believe in Allah and His Messenger and **the Book that He sent down** upon His Messenger and **the Scripture which He sent down before**. And whoever disbelieves in Allah, His angels, His books, His messengers, and the Last Day has certainly gone far astray.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat An-Nisa' 4:136](https://quran.com/4/136/)</sub>
- [Surat Al-Ma'idah 5:47](https://quran.com/5/47) again is asking Christians to judge by what Allah has **revealed** in the Gospel, which [َQur'an 7:157](https://quran.com/7/157) says it is to follow the prophet that they have in their Torah and their Gospel:

  > وَلْيَحْكُمْ أَهْلُ الْإِنجِيلِ بِمَا أَنزَلَ اللَّهُ فِيهِ وَمَن لَّمْ يَحْكُم بِمَا أَنزَلَ اللَّهُ فَأُولَٰئِكَ هُمُ الْفَاسِقُونَ
  >
  > And let the People of the Gospel judge by **what Allah has revealed therein**. And whoever does not judge by what Allah has revealed — then it is those who are the defiantly disobedient.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al-Ma'idah 5:47](https://quran.com/5/47)</sub>

  Note that this verse is contextual, as the [following verse](https://quran.com/5/48) says that the Qur'an is the one that supersedes, abrogates, and overrules all previous Scripture, but the article you quotes skipped that specific verse.
- [Surat Al-Ma'idah 5:49](https://quran.com/5/49) again is talking about what Allah has revealed, and this verse, in particular, goes further to forbid the Prophet ﷺ from following their inclinations

  > وَأَنِ احْكُم بَيْنَهُم بِمَا أَنزَلَ اللَّهُ وَلَا تَتَّبِعْ أَهْوَاءَهُمْ وَاحْذَرْهُمْ أَن يَفْتِنُوكَ عَن بَعْضِ مَا أَنزَلَ اللَّهُ إِلَيْكَ ۖ فَإِن تَوَلَّوْا فَاعْلَمْ أَنَّمَا يُرِيدُ اللَّهُ أَن يُصِيبَهُم بِبَعْضِ ذُنُوبِهِمْ ۗ وَإِنَّ كَثِيرًا مِّنَ النَّاسِ لَفَاسِقُونَ
  >
  > And judge, [O Muhammad], between them **by what Allah has revealed** and **do not follow their inclinations** and beware of them, lest they tempt you away from some of what Allah has revealed to you. And if they turn away — then know that Allah only intends to afflict them with some of their [own] sins. And indeed, many among the people are defiantly disobedient.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al-Ma'idah 5:49](https://quran.com/5/49)</sub>
- [Surat Al-Ma'idah 5:50-52](https://quran.com/5/50-52/) have nothing to do with the corruption of the Scripture as such. They talk about them not willing to abide by what Allah has revealed to the Prophet ﷺ in the Qur'an:

  > أَفَحُكْمَ الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ يَبْغُونَ وَمَنْ أَحْسَنُ مِنَ اللَّهِ حُكْمًا لِّقَوْمٍ يُوقِنُونَ يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا لَا تَتَّخِذُوا الْيَهُودَ وَالنَّصَارَىٰ أَوْلِيَاءَ ۘ بَعْضُهُمْ أَوْلِيَاءُ بَعْضٍ وَمَن يَتَوَلَّهُم مِّنكُمْ فَإِنَّهُ مِنْهُمْ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَهْدِي الْقَوْمَ الظَّالِمِينَ فَتَرَى الَّذِينَ فِي قُلُوبِهِم مَّرَضٌ يُسَارِعُونَ فِيهِمْ يَقُولُونَ نَخْشَىٰ أَن تُصِيبَنَا دَائِرَةٌ فَعَسَى اللَّهُ أَن يَأْتِيَ بِالْفَتْحِ أَوْ أَمْرٍ مِّنْ عِندِهِ فَيُصْبِحُوا عَلَىٰ مَا أَسَرُّوا فِي أَنفُسِهِمْ نَادِمِينَ
  >
  > Then is it the judgement of [the time of] ignorance they desire? But who is better than Allah in judgement for a people who are certain [in faith]. O you who have believed, do not take the Jews and the Christians as allies. They are [in fact] allies of one another. And whoever is an ally to them among you — then indeed, he is [one] of them. Indeed, Allah guides not the wrongdoing people. So you see those in whose hearts is disease hastening into [association with] them, saying, "We are afraid a misfortune may strike us." But perhaps Allah will bring conquest or a decision from Him, and they will become, over what they have been concealing within themselves, regretful.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al-Ma'idah 5:50-52](https://quran.com/5/50-52/)</sub>
- [Surat Yunus 10:94](https://quran.com/10/94/) does not talk about consulting previous Scripture; rather, it is talking about consulting those who read or studied previous Scripture, as the Prophet ﷺ did when he got his first revelation and consulted [Waraka ibn Nawfal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waraka_ibn_Nawfal) who told him that he had the signs of the prophet that was mentioned in the Torah of Moses. Having said that, the verse is contextual and is referring to specific Jews who embraced Islam, e.g., [Ka'b al-Ahbār](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka%E2%80%99b_al-Ahbar) and ['Abdullah ibn Salām](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdullah_ibn_Salam):

  > فَإِن كُنتَ فِي شَكٍّ مِّمَّا أَنزَلْنَا إِلَيْكَ فَاسْأَلِ الَّذِينَ يَقْرَءُونَ الْكِتَابَ مِن قَبْلِكَ لَقَدْ جَاءَكَ الْحَقُّ مِن رَّبِّكَ فَلَا تَكُونَنَّ مِنَ الْمُمْتَرِينَ
  >
  > So if you are in doubt, [O Muhammad], about that which We have revealed to you, then ask those who have been reading the Scripture before you. The truth has certainly come to you from your Lord, so never be among the doubters.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Yunus 10:94](https://quran.com/10/94/)</sub>
- [Surat Al-Anbya 21:7](https://quran.com/21/7/) is not asking Muslims to confer with the people of the Scripture; rather, it is addressing the disbelievers from among the Arabs who rejected the idea that Allah would send a human being as His messenger instead of sending an angel. The verse commands the disbelievers to confer with the people of the Scripture (who were living among them at the time) to check if previous messengers were men or angels; it is not to confer about their creed at large:

  > وَمَا أَرْسَلْنَا قَبْلَكَ إِلَّا رِجَالًا نُّوحِي إِلَيْهِمْ ۖ فَاسْأَلُوا أَهْلَ الذِّكْرِ إِن كُنتُمْ لَا تَعْلَمُونَ
  >
  > And We sent not before you, [O Muhammad], **except men to whom We revealed** [the message], so ask the people of the message if you do not know.
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al-Anbya 21:7](https://quran.com/21/7/)</sub>
- [Surat Al-'Ankabut 29:46](https://quran.com/29/46/) is not talking about question the authority of the Scriptures of the Christians at all; rather, it is about how Muslims should invite others to Islam when debating with the people of the Scripture (in a way that is best, except for those who commit injustice among them). As for the belief, again it is about what was revealed and not what they have among them now or then:

  > وَلَا تُجَادِلُوا أَهْلَ الْكِتَابِ إِلَّا بِالَّتِي هِيَ أَحْسَنُ إِلَّا الَّذِينَ ظَلَمُوا مِنْهُمْ ۖ وَقُولُوا آمَنَّا بِالَّذِي أُنزِلَ إِلَيْنَا وَأُنزِلَ إِلَيْكُمْ وَإِلَٰهُنَا وَإِلَٰهُكُمْ وَاحِدٌ وَنَحْنُ لَهُ مُسْلِمُونَ
  >
  > And do not argue with the People of the Scripture except in a way that is best, except for those who commit injustice among them, and say, "We believe in that **which has been revealed to us and revealed to you**. And our God and your God is one; and we are Muslims [in submission] to Him."
  >
  > <sub>— [Surat Al-'Ankabut 29:46](https://quran.com/29/46/)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

A few explicit verses:

> "Are you then eager that they [the People of the Book] should believe you, though **a part of them would hear the word of Allah and then they would distort it** after they had understood it, and they knew [what they were doing]?
>
> When they meet the faithful, they say, ‘We believe,’ and when they are alone with one another, they say, ‘**Do you recount to them what Allah has revealed to you**, so that they may argue with you therewith before your Lord? Do you not apply reason?’ (This is a recounting of the dishonesty the people had when showing their books)
>
> Do they not know that **Allah knows whatever they hide** and whatever they disclose? And among them are the illiterate who know nothing of the Book except hearsay, and they only make conjectures. (They priests used to hide parts of the book and now those parts are probably lost)
>
> **So woe to those who write the Book with their hands and then say, ‘This is from Allah,’** that they may sell it for a paltry gain. So woe to them for what their hands have written, and woe to them for what they earn!" (Explicit mention of people writing the books and claiming it to be holy) (2:75-79)

This is an explicit criticism of the People of the Book about their handling of the holy scriptures: they hid parts of it that they didn't like, and they added and wrote parts and claimed it is from Allah.

Here is a Tafsir from Ibn Abbas who is [very qualified](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/198) to interpret the Quran:

> Ibn Abbas said, "O Muslims? How do you ask the people of the Scriptures, though your Book (i.e. the Qur'an) which was revealed to His Prophet is the most recent information from Allah and you recite it, the Book that has not been distorted? Allah has revealed to you that the people of the scriptures have changed with their own hands what was revealed to them and they have said (as regards their changed Scriptures): This is from Allah, in order to get some worldly benefit thereby." Ibn `Abbas added: "Isn't the knowledge revealed to you sufficient to prevent you from asking them? By Allah I have never seen any one of them asking (Muslims) about what has been revealed to you." ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/52/46))

Answer (score -2):

Here is some direct evidence from a Hadith from [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/1)

> Aisha (The mother of the faithful believers) narrated:
>
> The commencement of the Divine Inspiration to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) was in the form of good dreams which came true like bright daylight, and then the love of seclusion was bestowed upon him. He used to go in seclusion in the cave of Hira where he used to worship (Allah alone) continuously for many days before his desire to see his family. He used to take with him the journey food for the stay and then come back to (his wife) Khadija to take his food likewise again till suddenly the Truth descended upon him while he was in the cave of Hira.
>
> The angel came to him and asked him to read. The Prophet (ﷺ) replied, "I do not know how to read." The Prophet (ﷺ) added, "The angel caught me (forcefully) and pressed me so hard that I could not bear it any more. He then released me and again asked me to read and I replied, 'I do not know how to read.' Thereupon he caught me again and pressed me a second time till I could not bear it any more. He then released me and again asked me to read but again I replied, 'I do not know how to read (or what shall I read)?' Thereupon he caught me for the third time and pressed me, and then released me and said, 'Read in the name of your Lord, who has created (all that exists), created man from a clot. Read! And your Lord is the Most Generous." (96.1, 96.2, 96.3) Then Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) returned with the Inspiration and with his heart beating severely.
>
> Then he went to Khadija bint Khuwailid and said, "Cover me! Cover me!" They covered him till his fear was over and after that he told her everything that had happened and said, "I fear that something may happen to me." Khadija replied, "Never! By Allah, Allah will never disgrace you. You keep good relations with your kith and kin, help the poor and the destitute, serve your guests generously and assist the deserving calamity-afflicted ones." Khadija then accompanied him to her cousin Waraqa bin Naufal bin Asad bin 'Abdul 'Uzza, who, during the pre-Islamic Period became a Christian and used to write the writing with Hebrew letters. He would write from the Gospel in Hebrew as much as Allah wished him to write. He was an old man and had lost his eyesight.
>
> Khadija said to Waraqa, "Listen to the story of your nephew, O my cousin!" Waraqa asked, "O my nephew! What have you seen?" Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) described whatever he had seen. Waraqa said, "This is the same one who keeps the secrets (angel Gabriel) whom Allah had sent to Moses. I wish I were young and could live up to the time when your people would turn you out." Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) asked, "Will they drive me out?" Waraqa replied in the affirmative and said, "Anyone (man) who came with something similar to what you have brought was treated with hostility; and if I should remain alive till the day when you will be turned out then I would support you strongly." But after a few days Waraqa died and the Divine Inspiration was also paused for a while.

Waraqa, is a cousain of Khadija; Khadija is the first wife of the Prophet. He is a Christian and supports the Prophet in the turmoil after the Divine Inspiration has descended upon him. He confirms his Prophetic vocation and links him with Moses. This is then an implicit acknowledgement of the authenticity of the Biblical and Talmudic tradition, if not in its details.

Comment: Please provide evidence that shows that if a portion of a book is authentic (the Scripture of Moses in this case), then the entire Scripture is authentic.

Comment: Using this hadith alone, in my opinion, proves that the Scripture was indeed corrupted as the verses that likened Mohammad ﷺ to Moses ﷺ can no longer be found or interpreted in this meaning. If indeed the authentic and authoratative verses that Waraqa referred to are still there, all Christians and Jews should as a minimum acknowledge the prophethood of Mohammad ﷺ as Waraqa did.

Comment: @III-AK-III: I wrote that 'this is an implicit acknowledgement of the authenticity of the Biblical & Talmudic tradition, if *not* in its details'; the question is not asking for 'proof' but whether 'Qu'ran endorses the Bible'; I used the Hadith rather than the Qu'ran; but I think that this is good enough given that the Hadith is part of the Sunnah.

Comment: @III-AK-III: the main error is theological. In that Christ is seen as the Son of God and not in any kind of metaphorical way. The error is a theological interpretation of the New Testament. I think there are Christians that don't go along with this, but in the main, they're an insignificant minority.

Comment: @III-AK-III: Moses appears in the Qu'ran but he is not compared to Muhammed there. This Hadith here is not a comparison of Muhammed with Moses, but endorsing the Prophetic vocation of Muhammed in the same way that Moses had a Prophetic vocation.

Comment: @III-AK-III: I don't see how my answer differs in essence (it obviously differs in how it is written) what you have said in your answer: 'The Qu'ran only endorses the Torah & the Bible as revealed by Allah and not those versions that are amongst us now'; I'd also add, that until someone actually finds the originals (and there's little hope of this), this is all we have of the Torah & the Bible.

Comment: @III-AK-III: sure, no problem.